# Sync Banshee with Ubuntu One music without having the music locally?

Tags: ubuntu-one, music, banshee, cloud

Is it possible to set up Banshee to sync with my Ubuntu One music that is stored in the cloud?

If I upload all my music to Ubuntu One from my desktop, will I then be able to sync Banshee with that cloud and play all my music on my laptop, without having to "download" all the music to my laptop?

Can Banshee handle the cloud music as if it was stored locally?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is unfortunately "no" (or at least not yet).

Answer (score 3):

It would be possibly for someone to write a Banshee extension which does this; Ubuntu One provides a music streaming API (documentation for which is at https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/music/stream_music/cloud/). No-one has so far written such an extension, but it's possible to do so, and I'd be happy to provide help to anyone wishing to do so.

Comment: unfortunately I am not skilled enough to do such a thing but I would definitely digg it if someone would make such an extension :)