# Desktop Player for Music Stored on Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, music

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sync Banshee with Ubuntu One music without having the music locally?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/36003/sync-banshee-with-ubuntu-one-music-without-having-the-music-locally)

Is there a linux desktop application available to playback music files stored on Ubuntu One?

Comment: what format are the files in?

Answer (score 0):

I know you can make a smart playlist that can play your Ubuntu One music just copy and paste the link to the music folder and paste it onto the smart playlist.